# Fragment in redirect with Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a few redirect rules that are not working as expected due to the fragment. Here is an example of the rules I am trying to get to work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.{2,5}/)?search/2016 /search?date=2016#grid [R=301,NC,L]
```

However, this redirects me to:

```
www.domain.com/search>date=2016%23grid
```

How do I set up my rewrite rules so the redirect is:

```
www.domain.com/search>date=2016#grid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`NE` (No Escape) flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.{2,5}/)?search/2016 /search?date=2016#grid [R=301,NC,L,NE]
```